# VCS decision help and information.

Tags: git, tfs, dvcs

I'm in the process of developing my first desktop application with the help of 1-2 other people. It's an application built on C#.

I'm kid of stumped on what to use as a VCS. I have a TFS service account and a micro Github account.

I've tried git-tf and TFVC and I do like both. I like the fact that I can have code reviews with TFS, planning etc. I like using git because we can branch per feature and then merge with master. I also like the fact that a copy of the source is kept on each individual's machine.

I'm am not sure if TFService does branching and merging like git does or if you can work offline with it.  What is the difference between commit and checkin/out.

What would be better for my small team to use?  I want to be able to control changes from branches (after thorough bug testing being able to merger to master etc). I like having work items, storyboard and sprint (it's easier for me to organize what needs to be done as I am extremely disorganized).

We need the ability to "see" what each other are working on etc.

This doesn't make any sense, as you can tell I'm lost on what I really need. 
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git or Subversion are your choices here.

Size does not matter.  Even single individuals working on their own should be using source code management.

Your decision is in-house or cloud.

GitHub and BitBucket are popular.  Why not go with one of those?

Comment: I have a free micro github account, I just like the other tools that TFS offers. I don't know how to submit code review with git or git-tf. With TFS it's as easy as right clicking on the file in Solution Exlporerr

Answer (score 0):

If you want all those services TFS is a good fit for your needs. If you are all familiar with git, I'd suggest using TFS with git rather than the legacy TFS source control as git is much more powerful.